# Is there a way to access the frame property of a UIImagePickerController's CAMPreviewView

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to access the `CAMPreviewViewController` frame in order to perfectly centre my `UIImagePickerController` overlay. My overlay needs to sit centrally over the 'camera view' and I want a way to ensure this is the case across all devices.

Opening the debug view hierarchy suggests that the `CAMPreviewView` would give me the `CGRect` I need. I'm struggling to get a handle on it.

[image: Debug View Hierarchy]